# Introductory book on Riemann Surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, riemann-surfaces

What is a good textbook (or set of online lecture notes) to start learning about Riemann surfaces? They were briefly mentioned in a complex analysis course I am taking, and seem like a very interesting topic, but I cannot find an introductory reference. I have a basic (2nd-year undergraduate level) knowledge of real and complex analysis and differential geometry. Thank you for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the suggestions in this closely related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200537).  You can also see this [post1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712071) and this [post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407004).